# Are there natural language examples of n-ary relations greater than 3?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, semantics, relations

Binary relations are obvious, and I see the need to have 3-ary relations such as "being in between things". Are there natural language examples of relations greater 3?

Edit: without combining binary or tertiary relations

Comment: Just take a conjunction (or any other binary operation) of two binary relations. A is a son of B, and C is a son D. [According to Quine's reduction theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2268616), a predicate of any arity can be reduced to a combination of binary predicates.

Comment: Any examples without combining binary or tertiary relations? And I guess "being in between" can be reduced to binaries, but there is a sense of it being a single emergent property of its own.

Comment: That does not exist, but one can make up examples where it is less obvious. A hit B with a C attached to a D. "Attached to" can be iterated indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks! Also interesting how it's ambiguous what is attached to D with this syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking about [predicate valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)) then there are a few examples of tritransitive/quadrivalent verbs with four arguments. For example:

> I<sup>1</sup> bet you<sup>2</sup> five dollars<sup>3</sup> that it would rain<sup>4</sup>.

Comment: @jobermark So what? This is an academic site and it's unreasonable to expect discussions to be kept at a high school level. The argument/adjunct distinction has been common in linguistics for decades. I don't think we can have a fruitful discussion when you call aktionsart a 'contrivance'.

Comment: @jobermark I really don't know why you're angry with me. I haven't said that history is dead or what you know is obsolete. In the comments on your answer I presented two diagnostic tests for why the temporal adverbs are adjuncts not arguments. If that's not relevant to your philosophy of language just say so. And, if possible, tell us what framework you *are* using.

Comment: @jobermark You never said your framework doesn't distinguish arguments from adjuncts. I thought you were trying to say that the temporal adverbs were arguments the whole way through.

Comment: @curiousdanii    You can leave out the direct object too, and have it implied.  And roles are not strictly positional in any language.  I can make an appositive and put the subject at the end -- the same response I made last time you offerd this same complaint

Comment: @jobermark I didn't at the beginning understand why you thought clausal adjuncts should count for 5-ary verb relations. If I understand correctly now you're considering the relation only in terms of functional roles and not at all in terms of grammar, syntax or what constituents a verb requires or licenses.

Comment: Yes, because the question was about useful n-ary relations relative to natural language.  What I gave was an example of exactly that.  And your initial complaint simply outright stated otherwise, because you consider other aspects of grammar more important.  But one does not have to do so.   I can see the point of abstracting adverbs and adjectives off with a common inheritance.  That does not change that adverbs play a given role in a sentence.  Also removeability is an accident of choice.  If I use told, I need a DO, if I choose said I don't.  But those are logical equivalents. So why care?

Comment: @jobermark I didn't mean to insult you and still don't really know what I said that would be insulting. Sorry if I was too sharp with you. And I don't mind if you want to reduce language to what's logically equivalent, but please don't dismiss the linguistic endeavour as a series of grammatical contrivances. The fact that English has two verbs *tell* and *say* while others have only one with inflections is an interesting part of human culture.

Comment: @curiousdanii.  I will not.  And this is pointless I am deleting all of it.  You will not extend the slightest consideration to my theory of things.  Yours *must* be considered right, or I owe you an apology?  Nope.  Not in this world.

Comment: @jobermark I've already said I acknowledge your model is different. I never said mine is the only way to look at things. But I also never insulted you by calling anything you talked about a contrivance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98683/discussion-between-jobermark-and-curiousdannii).

Answer (score 0):

I can't quickly think of ones very obviously corresponding to a word in a natural language (such as "between" for ternary). The best I can think of is "surrounded by", since presumably (living on a two-dimensional surface) one needs at least three things to be surrounded by -- one step up from between!

In principle one could make up a word for all kinds of quaternary relations such as:

- The relation between the four people on a double date.
- The relation between four athletes competing for one of the three spots on the podium.
- The relation between four points a, b, c, and d, where a and b want to be connected to each other and c and d want to be connected to each other but the line segments between them intersect.  (Such a relation may be useful to talk about a specific kind of problem in geopolitics.)

Answer (score 0):

A list of more than three items could be viewed as a relationship where each item in the list is connected by "and". For example,

> "Today I spent $20 on food, $40 on housing, $10 on entertainment and $30 dollars on transportation."

I could symbolize my spending (*S*) as one part for food (*f*), one part for housing (*h*), one part for entertainment (*e*) and one part for transportation (t) and then write the relation *S* with variables as *S(f,h,e,t)*.

I could break this up into four unary relations all connected by "and", but from a natural language perspective if I were telling someone what I spent, I would likely combine them into a 4-ary relation.